# Assign glob.iglob() results to a list

Tags: python, list, iterator

The `glob.iglob()`-function returns an iterator. How can I most effectively assign its "items" to a list in Python? I want the results in a list so that I can choose a random item with `random.choice()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `glob.glob` instead since it returns a list.

To build a list out of an arbitrary iterable, you just use the `list` builtin:

```
list(glob.iglob('*'))
```

Comment: @poplitea -- I doubt you can make glob case insensitive.  I think you can do thinks like `[aA]` to match either lowercase a or uppercase A.  Otherwise you might need to fall back on regex and `os.listdir`.

Comment: Thanks anyway for quick and explanatory answer. Knowing about the `list()`-function will come in handy anyhow.

Comment: `list` is actually a builtin type even though it's documented under `functions`.  I never know whether to call it a function or a type, but it's good to know... (`print(str(list))` vs `print(str(range))`)